# Cannot output correct file directories to a linked list with .cFileName

Tags: c, windows, file, directory

I'm trying to make a linked list with individual nodes having the names of files in my folder. With every additional folder, I'd like to output the whole linked list with the names of previous, already loaded files. I'm in my C:\Intel folder that has 2 files - *ExtremeGraphics* and *Logs*. This is my whole code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct item{
    char *data;
    struct item *next;
} tItem;

int insert(char *x, tItem **top){
    tItem *temp = (tItem *)malloc(sizeof(tItem));
    temp->data =    x;
    temp->next =    *top;
    *top       =    temp;
     tItem *iterator;
     iterator = *top;
    while(iterator!=NULL){//display whole linked list
        printf("\n\tNode data: %s, node next:0x%x\n", iterator->data, iterator->next);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    tItem *head = NULL;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind, hFind_2;

    hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\Intel\\*.*", &FindFileData);
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {    printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;}
   else
   {
      while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData))
      {
        printf ("\n\nNext file found is %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        insert(FindFileData.cFileName, &head);
      }
      FindClose(hFind);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Next file found is ..

        Node data: .., node next:0x0

Next file found is ExtremeGraphics

        Node data: ExtremeGraphics, node next:0x330f80

        Node data: ExtremeGraphics, node next:0x0

Next file found is Logs

        Node data: Logs, node next:0x330fa0

        Node data: Logs, node next:0x330f80

        Node data: Logs, node next:0x0
```

I have no idea why it gives me **the same ->data value** for every node in the case of *Logs* and *ExtremeGraphics*, I'm not overwriting it anywhere.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving a file name, you store a pointer to the `cFileName` member of the find data struct in the linked list. All the list elements will point there.

This `cFileName` member variable is overwritten by subsequent calls to `FindNextFile()` with the newly found file names. Since the list elements all just point there, printing them will print the last name repeatedly.

To really save the file name you have to store a copy of `cFileName` in the list, for example created with `strdup()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to dup x:

```
int insert(char *x, tItem **top){
    tItem *temp = (tItem *)malloc(sizeof(tItem));
    temp->data =    strdup(x);
    temp->next =    *top;
    *top       =    temp;
     tItem *iterator;
     iterator = *top;
    while(iterator!=NULL){//display whole linked list
        printf("\n\tNode data: %s, node next:0x%x\n", iterator->data, iterator->next);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```